# Enterprise Architet- Version Control error

Tags: svn, version-control, enterprise-architect

I use a Version Controlled EA model.

Recently I get the following error when I try to get latest:

```
 Reserved error (-1601); there is no message for this error.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: contact Sparx Systems's support